# Eclipse CDT: pkg-config indexing

Tags: bash, indexing, eclipse-cdt, pkg-config

I`m developing a application using gtkmm with eclipse. While I could have setup gtkmm include paths and linking options manually, i decided to let pkg-config do the work because of the huge number of referenced projects. This was quite easy as adding the appropriate pkg-config command to the compiler invocation worked just fine because one can simply use the

```
`...`
```

shell substitution since eclipse will generate a makefile which is then executed.

Setting up the indexer right isnt that easy though. Instead of executing shell script in a interpreter, eclipse executes the compiler directly and pass command line arguments directly without substituting them before.

How can one execute shell script when executing the indexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to execute the bash interpreter with the `-c` flag directly instead of executing g++.
For the scenario described in the question the configurations are as followed:

```
Compiler invocation command
   bash

Compiler invocation arguements
   -c "g++ `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags` -E -P -v -dD ${plugin_state_location}/specs.cpp"
```